# Datatable withbutton hide and show in angularjs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am new to angularjs. I am implementing a angularjs datatable with some json data. I am facing a problem that each time if a user had permission (which is stored in json) can export csv but when the user has no permission, the datatable export button is hidden or does not show. I googled some articles but am unable to find answer.

I used below code to implement datatable buttons:

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('')
  .withFnServerData(serverData)
  .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
  .withDataProp('data')
  .withOption('order', [0, 'desc'])
  .withOption('processing', true)
  .withOption('serverSide', true)
  .withOption('headerCallback', function(header) {
    if (!vm.headerCompiled) {
      // Use this headerCompiled field to only compile header once
      vm.headerCompiled = true;
      $compile(angular.element(header).contents())($scope);
    }
  })
  .withPaginationType('full_numbers')

  .withOption('lengthMenu', [
    [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, -1],
    [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, "All"]
  ])
  .withButtons([
    {
      className:'fa fa-upload',
      key: '1',
      action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
        vm.openImportFileDialog();
      }
    },
    {
      action:function () {
        if (!vm.permissions.assets_EDIT) {
          alert('You have no permission to download file.')
        }
      },
      extend: "csv",
      text:' Export(CSV)',
      className:'fa fa-download',
      exportOptions: {
        columns:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
      },
      exportData: {decodeEntities:true}
    },
    {
      className:'fa fa-exchange p-left-5',
      text:' Export(HTML)',
      // enabled: false,
      action:function () {
          vm.openNewTab();
      }
    }

  ])
  .withBootstrap();
```

Here is my html content:-

```
 <table  datatable="" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns" dt-instance="vm.dtInstance"
                   class="row-border hover">
            </table>
```

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Could you please paste your HTML.

Comment: @AnkitPandey, thanks for your response i updated the question.

Comment: "but when the user has no permission, the datatable export button is hidden or does not show" I am not able to see this logic in the code sample you posted, therefore I can't help :S

Comment: actually i store the permission value in vm.permissions.asset_EDIT variable , so each time when user logged in i want that on the basis of permission the button get hide or show.

Comment: An issue link is here https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/502

Comment: May be this plunker is for debugging
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/05TnMU

Comment: Was surprised to see this not was answered yet, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manage two set of buttons, one for users with permissions, another for users without. It could look like this :

```
var buttonsNoPermission = [{ extend: 'colvis' }];
var buttonsWithPermission = [{ extend: 'colvis' }, { extend: 'csvHtml5' }];
```

Simply port the params from your `.withButtons` to variables. Then you can create the relevant buttons for the user by a ternary in the initialization itself :

```js
.withButtons( permissions.asset_EDIT ? buttonsWithPermission : buttonsNoPermission)
```

Here is a small demo, try change `permissions.asset_EDIT` :

**http://plnkr.co/edit/s6lainDw4eQC9zaoZGdG?p=preview**

**Note**: I am not using the `vm` approach in the demo, so dont get confused, refer to `vm.permissions.asset_EDIT` in your own code. Have never really understood the concept behind `vm`, besides it is a way for lazy programmers to accidently add a new layer of complexity to their code :)

Answer (score -1):

Based on value of say `vm.showExportOption` you can add a class to the parent `table` element. Then with a little bit of CSS Logic you can hide the exact button by targeting its class based on whether or not a certain class is present on its parent.

Here's the rough idea:

On Table element:

```
ng-class="vm.showExportOption ? 'show-export' : 'hide-export'"
```

Then in CSS something like:

```
table.show-export .fa-exchange{
  display:block;
}

table.hide-export .fa-exchange{
  display:none;
}
```

Remember this is not to copy-paste but to give you an idea on how to do this. If you can create a JSFiddle to show your problem, I will gladly port it, but this should get you on you way.

Comment: Actually the code is prototype of 
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withButtons

Comment: @AnkitPandey and what exactly is your point? The answer would work no matter what library because it shows a strategy to do this.

Comment: @Shaunak, it makes all the difference. Angular DataTables is directives for jQuery dataTables, which dynamically inject buttons into a container. There is no way that you can use angular concepts or directives in that scenario, the buttons is completely detached from the angular flow.

Answer (score -2):

I would try adding an `ng-show` tag element tag, in your case the export button, with a backing *Boolean* variable that you can set in your code:

```
<table ng-show="!vm.dtIsHidden" datatable="" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns" dt-instance="vm.dtInstance"
               class="row-border hover">
        </table>
```

Then in your view model, set this value up with the proper logic:

```
 vm.dtIsHidden = whatever;
```

And this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response but i am try to show and hide a export button or you can say `.withButtons([
    {extend: "csv",
      text:' Export(CSV)',
      className:'fa fa-download',
      exportOptions: {
        columns:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
      },
      exportData: {decodeEntities:true}
    },`

Comment: this will hide the whole table

Comment: I only want to hide the export button of datatable which is created by above commented script.

Comment: Then you can put that ng-show on the export button element. It is not element specific.